# What trigger menu_rebuild flag in semaphore table?

Tags: routes, performance

Well, this question appear to be simple, but my problem is a little bit more complex. I'll try to explain my situation.

I have a site with customized template and a bunch of modules (all 3rd party from Drupal contrib site). When **any content** needs to be updated, which means include, update or delete a node, page or panel causes a slow down in entire site. The site practically stops. For everyone (anonymous and logged users).

I began an investigation and I realized that **menu_rebuild flag in semaphore table** is taking too long (~5 minutes) to disappear. This is causing trouble for every user who wants to  navigate on the website, because menu_rebuild is locking down the site.

One side effect of this menu_rebuild lock is the queue of apache processes in the server. This leads the server to be overloaded (100% CPU).

My conclusion after this investigation is simple. Something (a module maybe) is firing the menu_rebuild many times causing the site lockup. I tracked down the function in Drupal core that activate menu_rebuild. See:

**includes/menu.inc**

```
/**
 * Populates the database tables used by various menu functions.
 *
 * This function will clear and populate the {menu_router} table, add entries
 * to {menu_links} for new router items, and then remove stale items from
 * {menu_links}. If called from update.php or install.php, it will also
 * schedule a call to itself on the first real page load from
 * menu_execute_active_handler(), because the maintenance page environment
 * is different and leaves stale data in the menu tables.
 *
 * @return
 *   TRUE if the menu was rebuilt, FALSE if another thread was rebuilding
 *   in parallel and the current thread just waited for completion.
 */
function menu_rebuild() {

  if (!lock_acquire('menu_rebuild')) {
    // Wait for another request that is already doing this work.
    // We choose to block here since otherwise the router item may not
    // be available in menu_execute_active_handler() resulting in a 404.
    lock_wait('menu_rebuild');
    return FALSE;
  }

  $transaction = db_transaction();

  try {
    list($menu, $masks) = menu_router_build();
    _menu_router_save($menu, $masks);
    _menu_navigation_links_rebuild($menu);
    // Clear the menu, page and block caches.
    menu_cache_clear_all();
    _menu_clear_page_cache();

    if (defined('MAINTENANCE_MODE')) {
      variable_set('menu_rebuild_needed', TRUE);
    }
    else {
      variable_del('menu_rebuild_needed');
    }
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
    watchdog_exception('menu', $e);
  }

  lock_release('menu_rebuild');

 return TRUE; 
}
```

When I comment the `lock_wait('menu_rebuild');` / `lock_release('menu_rebuild');` calls, my site runs smoothly and fast. But I can't do that. This affects the generation of new content.

I disabled all modules that I could without breaking the template. If you need to know what modules that I have installed, please ask.

I am using Drupal 7.23. My server configuration:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- 4 cores / 8GB RAM
- Apache 2.2.22;
- PHP 5.3.10 / FastCGI;

If you need information about apache configuration or PHP configuration, please let me know.

Update:

Here are all active modules in my site:

**[CORE]**

- Block
- Contact
- Content translation
- Contextual links
- Dashboard;
- Field;
- Field SQL Storage;
- Field UI;
- File
- Filter;
- Image;
- List;
- Locale;
- Menu;
- Node;
- Number;
- Options;
- Overlay;
- Path;
- RDF;
- Shortcut;
- System;
- Taxonomy;
- Text;
- Toolbar;
- Update Manager;
- User;

**[FIELDS]**

- Entity Reference;
- Link;
- Select(or other);

**[ACCESS CONTROL]**

- ACL;

**[SPAM CONTROL]**

- CAPTCHA;
- Image CAPTCHA;

**[DATE/HOUR]**

- Date;
- Date API;
- Date Popup;
- Date Views;

**[EMAIL]**

- Newsletter;
- SMTP Authentication Support

**[USER INTERFACE]**

- CKEditor;
- Options element;
- Pagestyle;

**[META TAGS (QUICK)]**

- Meta tags (quick);

**[LOCALIZATION]**

- Localization update;

**[INTERNATIONALIZATION]**

- Block languages;
- Contact translation;
- Field translation;
- Internationalization
- Menu translation;
- Multilingual contant;
- Multilingual select;
- Path translation;
- String translation;
- Synchronize translations
- Taxonomy translation;
- Translation redirect;
- Translation sets;
- Variable translation;

**[MEDIA]**

- File entity;
- IMCE;
- IMCE Mkdir;
- Media

**[OTHERS]**

- Entity API;
- Pathauto;
- Profile2;
- Profile2 pages;
- Token;
- Transliteration;
- Vocabulary Permissions Per Role;

**[PANELS]**

- Panels;

**[SUITE CHAOS TOOLS]**

- Chaos tools;
- Page manager;
- Views content panes;

**[VARIABLE]**

- Variable;
- Variable realm;
- Variable store;
- Variable views;

**[VIEWS]**

- Embed Views Display;
- Views;
- Views UI;

**[WEBFORM]**

- Webform;
- Webform validation;

**[WEBFORM DYNAMIC SELECT]**

- Webform options;

**[WORKBENCH]**

- Workbench;
- Workbench access;
- Workbench Media;
- Workbench Profile;

**[XML SITEMAP]**

- XML sitemap;
- XML sitemap engines;
- XML sitemap internationalization;
- XML sitemap menu;
- XML sitemap node;
- XML sitemap taxonomy;

Comment: Can you provide a list of the modules?

Comment: preferably mark those you already have disabled when you provide the list of modules.

Comment: You could throw a `watchdog('menu_rebuild', '<pre>' . print_r(debug_backtrace(), TRUE) . '</pre>');` into the menu_rebuild function, that should show all the routes into it in the watchdog log

Comment: @Steven, I updated my question with all enabled modules.

Comment: @arpitr, I didn't put the disabled modules. Do you need it?

Comment: No not disabled modules, but the thing that Clive wrote would also help.

Comment: And just to double check, those modules are ALL enabled right?

Comment: @Steven, yes. The modules listes are all enabled.

Comment: @Clive, using your hint, I found something. When I call the front page, the menu_rebuild() is triggered, and what is wrote in watchdog is HUGE (~1MB of data)! Looking to this information, I also found the function `block_page_build` with more than 3000 arrays inside. `[args] => Array` (>~3000).

Comment: Ouch that's a lot of data. Try using something like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php#112238) to get a meaningful trace of the function calls

Comment: Yah run a backtrace on it and maybe post the results in here. `block_page_build` should not have more then 3000 arrays lol. It should have a bunch but you probably don't have a 100 blocks on your page.

Comment: I disabled the block module (core) and the site works much faster. But, the most of the content has gone without blocks. The template has 59 regions defined and the site have ~1 block  for each region. Next step I'll run the backtrace.

Comment: Well, I pasted the content of debug of the menu_rebuild function to watchdog. Take a look: http://tny.cz/b5aaca3f

Comment: Well, the problem is the template. We hired a supplier to develop a template for our company. Badly coded. Thanks for your help guys. If the supplier resolve this problema, I will update this question. Tks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long wait, we finally figured out what is the real problem. This can be splitted in two parts: the custom template that we use and the [Chaos Tools Module](https://drupal.org/project/ctools).

1. The template **was really bad coded**. Had functions accessing the database all the time and making unnecessary I/O. We refactored the template;
2. [Chaos Tools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) is a really nice module, but it really slow down my site. Not all Chaos Tools, but specifically the **Page Manager**. I don't know why, but there is a loop in file `/sites/all/modules/ctools/page_manager/page_manager.module` causing all the trouble when I was trying to save a new page, for example. **This loop trigger menu_rebuild** semaphore and the **page manager** take an eternity to remove this flag from semaphore table.

Open the file page_manager.module and **scroll down to line ~148**

```
// And for those that provide subtasks, provide menu items for them, as well.
foreach (page_manager_get_task_subtasks($task) as $subtask_id => $subtask) {
   // Allow the task to add its own menu items.
   if ($function = ctools_plugin_get_function($task, 'hook menu')) {
      $function($items, $subtask);
   }
}
```

I commented this entire loop to solve this problem. I don't know all the impact this action can cause to my site, but now, when I save a new content, the speed increased and the `menu_rebuild` is not triggered.

```
// And for those that provide subtasks, provide menu items for them, as well.
// foreach (page_manager_get_task_subtasks($task) as $subtask_id => $subtask) {
//   Allow the task to add its own menu items.
//   if ($function = ctools_plugin_get_function($task, 'hook menu')) {
//      $function($items, $subtask);
//   }
// }
```

I believe **this is not a bug on Chaos Tools**, but maybe this can be improved.

Comment: My server's usage was insanely high. I reached this page via http://serverfault.com/questions/541604/apache-consuming-too-much-cpu-and-memory#comment679567_561065 and your suggestion seems to work! What do you mean when you say "menu_rebuild flag in semaphore table is taking too long (~5 minutes) to disappear"? Haven't used Drupal since a long time

Comment: Most probably the problem is not your server. Just make sure it is configured right. I don't know much about `menu_rebuild_flag`. All I know is this `menu_rebuild_flag` is used by some Drupal functions and modules too. However, this is not a problem at all when used with caution. This flag can lock the site if it was active. If some module need to lock to do some routine, the module can trigger this flag. To check the flag on yout database, just do: `select * from semaphore`

Answer (score 0):

To figure out an issue like this, you should enable XHProf, which is a tool that will profile your CPU (and memory) usage and will show you how the trace of calls through the system that calls this function.  From that you can find out what module or section of code that is causing the issue.

There is a great [page documenting how to set up Drupal and XHProf](https://drupal.org/node/946182), and let us and the module owners know what you find.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But, after a long wait, we figured out that the problem was the template and Chaos Tools. I explain better on my answer.